# Bluetooth is working, but the Wireless card is not detected AzureWare AW-NB126H Model AR5B225

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, bluetooth

I'm running on a ASUS N550JV notebook, with Combo Wireless and Bluetooth card AzureWare AW-NB126H, and the bluetooh part is working, but the wifi stopped to work last day, wireless card should be AR5B225.

I run the diagnostic wireless script, and here's the output.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Sep 2015 19:20 CEST +0200

Booted last: 20 Sep 2015 18:10 CEST +0200

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-49-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 9 10:03:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, acpi_osi=, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:11cd]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rndis_wlan             50291  0 
rndis_host             14513  1 rndis_wlan
usbnet                 43952  3 rndis_host,rndis_wlan,cdc_ether
cfg80211              498458  1 rndis_wlan
ath3k                  17427  0 
bluetooth             446409  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
asus_nb_wmi            21128  0 
asus_wmi               24094  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19193  1 asus_wmi
video                  20128  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.58  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'usb0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3096 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:3309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1899237 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:768978 (768.9 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1010     1  0 18:10 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: usb0  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            rndis_host
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.42.58
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.42.129

    DNS:             192.168.42.129

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-49-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     046346857FD53951C911443
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        ED:CF:BF:81:5A:6E:CA:BE:5C:35:0D:4A:AF:8A:8B:80:AE:A6:16:B6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     63F71F64CC07CB4CB9BDFAC
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        ED:CF:BF:81:5A:6E:CA:BE:5C:35:0D:4A:AF:8A:8B:80:AE:A6:16:B6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0032 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

I also checked the hardware, and removed the card, and put it back, but still no luck, I was thinking to purchase an Intel 7260 wireless card, but on current card I have the bluetooth part is still working.

Please let me know should I proceed.

Now I'm writing from the notebook, connected to internet through USB by making tethering from my phone.

Comment: The wifi card might be broken, check BIOS settings to see if there is anything disabled for Wifi/WLAN

Comment: @Jeremy31 : thank you for comment, I already checked and the Wifi/WLAN card is not disabled. Can it brake without any reason?

Comment: It is an electronics device, a diode could have went bad and cause the thing not to function.  I would try it with a Live version of Ubuntu just to rule out an issue with a driver for PCI

Comment: @Jeremy31: I tried with a live version from an USB stick, but still no luck. I'll head tomorrow to the nearest shop and buy a TP-LINK WLAN USB adapter until I'll replace also the internal one, maybe Intel 7260?

Comment: @Jeremy31: Quick update - I bought another card and installed but is still the same behaviour, bluetooth is working, but not the wifi.

Comment: Check `dmesg | grep -i ath` and see if there are any errors